# where is scala get() method been defined

Tags: scala

```
def twoSum(param1: List[Int], param2: Int) = {
    val gb = ((param1 combinations 2 toList) find (_.sum == param2) get)
    val gb2 = gb map (param1.indexOf(_)) sorted
    val index1 = gb2(0)+1
    val index2 = gb2(1)+1
    println(s" index1 = ${index1}, index2 = ${index2}")
}
```

In this code, it's using get at second line. my question is where is scala get() method been defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`find`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]) returns an [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Option).

You are therefore calling the [`get`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Option@get:A) method of the [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.Option) class.

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns an `Option`, so the `get` method being called here is defined in the `Option` class. Specifically it is defined as abstract in `Option` and the concrete definitions are given in its subclass `Some` and its "subobject" `None`.